# Making an Operating System Give More Memory Access to Erlang

Tags: linux, unix, memory, erlang, mnesia

I have always run erlang applications on powerful servers. However, sometimes, you cannot avoid such memory errors, especially when users are many

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 467078560 bytes of memory (of type "heap").
```

What makes it more annoying is that you have a server with 20GB of RAM, with say 8 cores. Looking at the memory which erlang says, it could not allocate and that is why it crashed, is also disturbing , because it is very little memory compared to what the server has in stock.
My question today (i wish it is not closed) , is that, what Operating system configurations can be done (consider RedHat , Solaris, Ubuntu or Linux in general), to make it offer the erlang VM more memory when it needs it ? 
If one is to run an erlang application on such capable servers, what memory consideration (outside erlang) should be made as regards the underlying operating system ? 
**Problem Background**
 Erlang consumes Main Memory, especially when processes are in thousands. I am running a Web service using `Yaws Web Server`. On the same node, i have Mnesia running with about 3 `ram_copies` tables. Its a notification system, as part of a larger Web application running on an intranet. Users access this very system via JSONP from the main application running off a different web server and a different hardware as well. Each user connection queries mnesia directly for any data it needs. However, as users increase i always get the `crash dump`. I have tweaked the application itself as much as possible, clean up the code to standard, used more binaries than strings e.t.c. avoided single points like gen_servers between yaws processes and mnesia, so that each connection, just hits mnesia directly. The server is very capable with lots of RAM and Disc Space. However, my node crashes when it needs a little more memory, thats why i need to find a way of forcing the Operating system to expand more memory to erlang. Operating system is `REDHAT ENTERPRISE 6`

Comment: How much memory was the Erlang VM using when it crashed? How much free RAM and swap was there?

Comment: swap was 8GB and free memory, around 17 GB. With Erlang, the operating system and a few other routines using the 2.5 GB to make up the 20 GB

Comment: What Erlang VM are you running? 32 bit, 64 bit or halfword?

Comment: 32 bit on a 64 bit Operating system

Comment: Hm, what does `ulimit -a` say?  (Note that this depends on the current user, and sometimes special limits are set for system processes, etc etc)  And what does `erlang:memory()` return? (ideally just before the system crashes)

Comment: `core file size (blocks, -c) = 0, data seg size (kbytes, -d) = unlimited,scheduling priority (-e) = 0,file size (blocks, -f) = unlimited,pending signals  (-i) = 15603,max locked memory (kbytes, -l) = 64,max memory size (kbytes, -m) = unlimited,open files (-n) = 1024,pipe size (512 bytes, -p) = 8,POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) = 819200,real-time priority (-r) = 0,stack size (kbytes, -s) = 10240
,cpu time (seconds, -t) = unlimited,max user processes (-u) = 1024,
virtual memory(kbytes, -v) = unlimited,file locks(-x) = unlimited`

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use 32-bit Erlang? You can build Erlang as a 64-bit process (or deploy the same via a package manager) on most (all?) supported 64-bit platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several various server tutorials I have read say that if the service runs as a non root user, you may have to edit the /etc/security/limits.conf to allow that user to access more memory than it is typically allowed. the example below lets user fooservice use 2GB.

```
fooservice      hard    memlock   2097152
```

Answer (score 4):

It is probably because you are running in 32bit mode where only approx 4 GB of RAM is addressable. Try switching to the 64bit version of erlang and try again.

Comment: It may be even less. The high bit is often reserved for the OS (though I don't know if that's the case for a 32-bit process on a 64-bit Linux).